# Want to add post to user dashboard

Tags: plugins, users, user-roles, author, capabilities

I would like to add `edit.php` to user dashboard who registers as subscriber on a website. Code which i using is

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){
if(!current_user_can('subscriber'))
    add_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //dashboard
}
```

even has administrator instead subscriber didn't work

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, could you clarify what you actually want to add to the subscriber role. Do you want the user to see all postings because `edit.php` allows to enter the listing which holds all the posts. And what do you mean with *user dashboard* because Dashboard is a Tab on the Administration panel in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code as below

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
function remove_menus(){
   $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = ( array ) $user->roles;
        if($role[0]==subscriber)
    add_menu_page( 'edit.php' ); //dashboard
```

}

Comment: no it doesnt show up

Comment: updated code please check it once

Comment: sorry didnt work

Comment: @Pratikbhatt, you realize that even for displaying the post listing there must be another cap added to that role. And til this moment(6 hours after the question) it is not clear from the question if the OP also wants to give/allow the option to edit/create a post. I assume not because(imho) then he/she would simply add the user to contributor role and maybe add restriction and so on.

Comment: yes changed role to author and now it working thanks. need to put all links in array adding end ($menu); while (prev($menu)){ $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]); if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}

Answer (score -1):

`function add_custom_caps() {
    global $wp_roles;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) ) {
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
    }
    $role = get_role( 'subscriber' );
    foreach ($wp_roles->get_role('editor')->capabilities as $key => $value){
        $role->add_cap( $key );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_custom_caps');`

It will clone all capability of Editor role and add them to Subscriber role

Comment: You are kidding or? Why would you add ALL caps of an editor, the OP just want the subscriber to have an option to see a list with all the Postings in the back-end. (Because `edit.php` holds the listing with posts in the back-end) Please [read here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) what you want the OP to add and understand that your way will have huge impact with possible negative impact.